# select record from mysql_fetch_assoc after putting into table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

not sure how feasable this is, but I have just rolled my own user search form, which simply queries my database and returns all the results with any given username, or similar using the LIKE 'some_username%' statement.

My search works great, and im really chuffed with myself as I am a php and mysql novice.

I used a mysql_fetch_assoc($result) statement, and then used a while loop to echo out each row from the database into an html table.

What I would then like to be able to do, is select a record from the table, and open a new page, which is populated with all the fields for that record, which I can then use to edit and update the user settings.

I thought perhaps one way to do it, is to perhaps echo out a form instead? that way I can have a button next to each row, to post the fields into some php code on my new page? I thought this may be a bit clunky though, and not sure how I would go about echoeing out a different form for each row.

Don;t know if anyone had any ideas on the best way to do this? If you need any code examples of what im working with, I can post them here.

Thanks very much!!
Eds

Comment: I think it's a good idea to post the code you have in your question. So answerers can build on that. Very few people will write a complete example for you.

Comment: Its simple programing logic. Just read more tutorial about user system programing and so on.

Comment: Thanks guys, i will try and find some premade code and reverse engineer to try and figure out my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

not a form but a hyperlink.
I wonder why you aren't familiar with this way of opening new pages as it is used everywhere.

just create a hyperlink

```
<a href="edit.php?id=1">name</a>
```

here is a sketch example of such an application, editing only one field, but you can add any number as well:

a main script:

```
<?  
mysql_connect(); 
mysql_select_db("new"); 
$table = "test"; 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { //form handler part: 
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
  if ($id = intval($_POST['id'])) { 
    $query="UPDATE $table SET name='$name' WHERE id=$id"; 
  } else { 
    $query="INSERT INTO $table SET name='$name'"; 
  } 
  mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query); 
  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);  
  exit;  
}  
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) { //listing part: 
  $LIST=array(); 
  $query="SELECT * FROM $table";  
  $res=mysql_query($query); 
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $LIST[]=$row; 
  include 'list.php'; 
} else { // form displaying part: 
  if ($id=intval($_GET['id'])) { 
    $query="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id=$id";  
    $res=mysql_query($query); 
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) $row[$k]=htmlspecialchars($v); 
  } else { 
    $row['name']=''; 
    $row['id']=0; 
  } 
  include 'form.php'; 
}  
?>
```

and two simple templates responsible for output,
one for the displaying the form, form.php

```
<? include TPL_TOP ?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$row['name']?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
<input type="submit"><br>
<a href="?">Return to the list</a>
</form>
<? include TPL_BOTTOM ?>
```

and one to display the list, list.php

```
<? include TPL_TOP ?>
<a href="?id=0">Add item</a>
<? foreach ($LIST as $row): ?>
<li><a href="?id=<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['name']?></a>
<? endforeach ?>
<? include TPL_BOTTOM ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this example. I am trying to give it a go, as I am completely unfamiliar with this kind of working, as im still learning. It seems to trip up at the line in the first code block, at the "foreach" statement, as when I click on the link, it returns "$v) $row[$k]=htmlspecialchars($v); } else { $row['name']=''; $row['id']=0; } include 'form.php'; } ?> "

Comment: I have made sure to include the correct sql server details, with my password, and I have created a new database called "new" with a table called "test", but not sure where I am going wrong with this one.

Comment: errr... try to replace  `<?=` with `<?php echo ` and <?` with `<?php`

Comment: Hi Colnel! Thanks, have changed those and it all loads correctly, but i dont quite understand what it is supposed to do. When entering anything in the form and pressing submit, all it does is take me to another page with a link that says add item. this takes me back to the form. Sorry, i think this is just too far out of my abilities.

Comment: it should add new rows to the list

Comment: unfortunately that did not help. Thanks for your assistance, i think i will try to dumb down my page a bit. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

always start php like this <?php, usually php manual configuration do not support short tag like this <?. 
for hyperlink just use view record
It is just query string and get id on next page like this
$id = $_GET['id'];
Hope u will understand..